# CKeditor cannot find ckeditor.js

Tags: wysiwyg

I am in the process of upgrading a Drupal install from 6 to 7. Drupal 6 uses the ckeditor module without any difficulties.

As I upgraded to Drupal 7 and the latest version of ckeditor, the module no longer works.

Firebug gives me an error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://mysite/ckeditor.js?mcqjp7
```

I'm not sure why ckeditor is looking in the site room for that file.

It has no trouble finding the css file

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://mysite/cms/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.css?mcqjp7");
```

So why can it find the CSS file but not the JS file?

Comment: Path differs for css and js ... For css entire path is taken but js path is broken... http://mysite/ckeditor.js?mcqjp7 , http://mysite/cms/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.css?mcqjp7

Comment: That makes sense but how can I get it to look in the right place for the js file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

You have to check the libraries for ckeditor in your drupal site.

```
sites/all/libraries/ckeditor
```

In D7 the CKEditor contain the libraries for editor. if you don't have then download the module and library from http://ckeditor.com/download

Comment: In Drupal 6, I was able to get away with just having it in sites/all/modules/ckeditor. But this solution worked.

Comment: For some unknown reason, I'm getting the 404 message again. I do have the ckeditor copied out to sites/all/libraries/ so I'm not sure why I get the 404 message now.

Comment: It is not mandatory that you are getting error from CKeditor. You need to check manually your issue.

Comment: The error is that Drupal is looking for the ckeditor.js in the site root directory instead of sites/all/libraries/ckeditor or sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor